# Methods are called as thread! Are they in a ordered stack?

Tags: c#

I have this code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
    printValue(i);
}

private void printValue(int value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

is there any case in which the numbers printed are not in order?

I mean, maybe the thread of the method printValue(60) is executed before than printValue(50)? (just as example).

Or they are synchronized?

Comment: Parallel.For or Parallel.ForEach ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see from this snippet, there is only one thread, which is sequentially executing the `printValue` function calls.  So there is no question of synchronization, because there is only one thread.

Comment: Uhm...I don't think so (but maybe I'm wrong). When I call printValue, the current cycle (in the for) doesnt waiting for the return of the printValue function... so it open a thread for the method... (or at least, I think so...)

Comment: @markzzz Do you mean that the function that contains the loop is called by multiple threads?

Comment: @markzzz, it most certainly will wait for `printValue` to return.  I can't speak for all programming languages, but C# certainly doesn't spin up a thread every time you call a function with a `void` return type.

Comment: No! Sorry for my english :) I mean : every time I do a cycle in the for (let i=4) I call the method printValue. But the for doesnt wait the end of printValue; now i=5, and maybe the printValue is not executed yet! Do you understand what I mean now?

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean.  But `printValue` would have to finish executing with the value of `i=4` before the loop would start executing with the value `i=5`.

Comment: The for has to wait for all statements in its block to execute (sequentially) before it can continue...

Comment: @dsolimano : really? And why this? I thought every time I call a method C# create a thread for that method, no?

Comment: @markzzz, no, that's is not what happens.  Do you have any links to documentation where it says that is what happens?

Comment: No :) That's why I asked here :)

Comment: Console.writeline only adds to the buffer hence returns before you see it on screen

Answer (score 1):

If your loop is within a function that is called by multiple threads:

```
private void Foo()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
  {
      printValue(i);
  }
}
```

Then there is absolutely no guarantee that the each thread's values will be displayed in order.

Answer (score 1):

how is the loop invoked? This decides how the printValue Method is called. If you call the loop in 2 parallel Tasks the output would definitly mix up!

To ensure, that the output is always right orderd you have to get the sensitive part of the code "thread safe". Take a look at http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx for further information about thread synchronization.

Try this to get "thread safe"

```
public class SomeClass{

    private static object lockObject = new object();

    public void Foo(){

        lock(lockObject){
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                printValue(i);
            }
        }

    }

    private void printValue(int value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

Offcourse there are may solutions for thread safty but this should work fine :-)